# How to relogin to root after killall -u root?

Tags: linux, ssh, kill, suse

I had done a silly thing and pressed enter on the command:

```
$ killall -u root
```

And now we can't log in. The last command ran was:

```
ws4-clarind:~ # killall -u root
Connection to ws4-clarind.esc.rzg.mpg.de closed by remote host.
Connection to ws4-clarind.esc.rzg.mpg.de closed.
xxx@con99:~> ssh root@ws4-clarind.esc.rzg.mpg.de
ssh: connect to host ws4-clarind.esc.rzg.mpg.de port 22: Connection refused
```

How could i restore root's login to the server?

Comment: I'd say a powerdown and backup is your only option? Never been in that situation before.  Is the console still active? if so, login using that and do a clean shutodwn / reboot.

Comment: it's a vm in a vm...

Comment: Ok, can you get to the console through the VM manager? If you can, the login process should be on a respawn - although if cron has died I'm not sure what the state will be.  If you can login, /etc/init.d/network restart && /etc/init.d/sshd restart *might* work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only restart the server at this point, as a ton of processes that are autostarted on startup and that are integral to the function of such a server were killed, including (possibly) init, the parent of all processes. You're going to have to restart the server.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the physical server on-premise. Connect the monitor and login with root. Once login run the comment #**/etc/init.d/sshd restart**. Afterward, you can able to access the ssh remotely